# Embedding a view block in template files makes output disappear

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a block that I need to embed in a node's Body field. I've tried `module_invoke()` + PHP Filter, and I've also tried the [Insert Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block) module. In both cases, whenever I embed a Views block, it makes the entire Body field disappear from the rendered page.

Embedding a Block-module block does *not* make it disappear; the block renders normally. I should also note that when using `module_invoke()`, that function call itself is sufficient to break the page; even if I delete the `print render()` line, it's still broken.

More info as I find it:

- When the page is broken, `dpm()` calls in `node.tpl.php` do not output anything.
- Oh, and I forgot to mention that no PHP errors are being generated. Which I can barely believe too.
- When the my embed attempts are active, the `system_main` block array is entirely missing from `$page['content']` in page.tpl.php. The `#sorted` flag is missing from there as well.
- Shabir's method below yields the same behavior as the other two methods I've tried.
- `dpm()`ing the block array (or Shabir's function's return value) shows the block contents as expected. However, the act of rendering the block makes none of the page content get printed.

Anyone have any ideas as to what's happening?

Now I'm having the problem when I call `module_invoke()` inside the views-view-unformatted--%.tpl.php file. All the view templates will send `dpm()` calls where they should go, but the content just disappears.

Furthermore, when I `dpm($page)` in page.tpl.php, `$page['content']['system_main']['main']['#markup']` shows a bunch of content for the site's front page! It still doesn't show up, though.

Comment: As it is a views block try with views_embed_view

Comment: It might be helpful if you share the code from your views template file.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following snippet in your template.php

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_render_block($module, $delta, array $options = array()){
  $default_options = array(
    'title' => '<none>',
    'region' => -1,
  );

  $options = array_merge($default_options, $options);

  $block = db_query('SELECT * FROM {block} WHERE module = :module AND delta = :delta', array(':module' => $module, ':delta' => $delta))->fetchObject();
  if($block) {
    $block = block_load($module, $delta);
    $block->title = $options['title'];
    $block->region = $options['region'];
    $blocks = array($block);
    $rblocks = _block_render_blocks($blocks);
    $render_array = _block_get_renderable_array($rblocks);
    return drupal_render($render_array);
  }
  return "";
}
```

This will ensure the block exist in next step call this function in your body

```
print YOURTHEMENAME_render_block('views', 'block-id',array('title'=>'your title of the block if any'));
```

I hope it will work fine in any case!

Comment: No good; doing this yields the exact same behavior as the other two methods I've tried.

Comment: Is there anything showing up in dpm()

Comment: I forgot to add this before: With any method, I can `dpm()` the array block. I can also `dpm()` your function's results and see the entire block's markup perfectly constructed. But the entire page contents are still empty.

Comment: Hmm, Can I have a screenshot how you are rendering the body field?